Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)}{n}$ convergent??
At first sight I answered that this series is divergent to my teacher, but just after a moment I realized that this is a tricky series with the term alternating, the difficult part of this question is that the terms of this series does not alternate one after another.

Try Dirichlet's test. If you are familiar with $\sin(n)$ being the imaginary part of $e^{in}$, it is much easier to show the sequence $\sin(n)$ has bounded partial sums.

@Mark ok thanks..

I do not have a proof so far, but at least mathematica states that the series converges, with the limit being $1/2 * (\pi-1)$

The trick is called summation by parts:
How do you show $\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin x}xdx$ converges in the sense of improper Riemann integral? IbP gives you $\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin x}xdx=-\frac{\cos x}x|_{x=1}^\infty-\int_1^\infty\frac{\cos x}{x^2}dx$, the right hand side of which converges.
For series we have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (A_{n+1}-A_n)B_n=A_nB_n|_{n=1}^\infty-\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_{n+1}(B_{n+1}-B_n)$. Choose $A_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\sin k$ and $B_n=\frac1n$ this is what you need.
Finally notice that $A_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\sin k$ is a bounded sequence because
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin k= \frac{\sin1+\sin n-\sin(n+1)}{2(1-\cos 1)}.$$
Combining with $B_{n+1}-B_n=\frac1{n(n+1)}=O(n^{-2})$, this concludes that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |A_{n+1}(B_{n+1}-B_n)|<\infty$.

As $-\frac1n\le\frac{sin(n)}{n}\le\frac1n$, so when n goes to infinity, $0\le\frac{sin(n)}{n}\le0$, so $a_n$ converges.

This argues that the sequence converges, not the series.

Probably what is meant is $\sum \frac{\sin(n)}{n}$, not just the sequence $\sin(n)/n$.

@Ian Even if so, it is still wrong. Comparison tests can be only used for series on non negative terms. And the harmonic series is divergent anyway.

More precisely I meant "probably what is meant in the OP is the series, not the sequence, so saying the sequence goes to zero doesn't allow us to conclude anything about the series". I was not replying to Randall.

@Ian Oh, ok then.
